# Trouble with the constraints, optimizing a shortest path exercise with CVXPY

Tags: python, optimization, shortest-path, cvxpy, operations-research

I'm a newbie in coding and I'm taking an operations research course. We're using cvxpy library to solve some exercises. I was told to create one by my own and I'm trying to optimize a shortest path exercise, but I'm having a hard time with the constraints.

I'm trying to add a constraint like this, but I don't know how to do it since the constraints in the library are listed

```
for i in range(nc+1):
    for j in range(nc+1):
        asig[i,j] != asig[j,i]
```

I would appreciate any help!

```
asig = cp.Variable((nc+1,nc+1), boolean = True) 

excel_1 = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vTAnqb05pTL8xrEzLgHPvi_xb3ciSiPf9xEzi5mx3id1a7ySvXbSEzDewsYwZ5_4A/pub?output=xlsx'
tabla_dist = pd.read_excel(excel_1, header=None)
coef_dist = np.zeros((nc+1,nc+1))

for i in range(0,nc+1):
    for j in range(0,nc+1):
        coef_dist[i][j] = tabla_dist.iloc[i,j]

coef_costos = cp.Parameter((nc+1,nc+1))
coef_costos = coef_dist

z_min = cp.Minimize(cp.sum(cp.multiply(coef_costos, asig)))

cond_1 = cp.sum(asig, axis=1) == 1
cond_2 = cp.sum(asig, axis=0) == 1
cond_3 = cp.diag(asig) == 0

restricciones = [cond_1,cond_2,cond_3]

problema = cp.Problem(z_min, restricciones)
problema.solve()
print("Estado de la solución:", problema.status)
print(problema.value)
print(asig.value)

matriz = np.array(asig.value)

for i in range(nc+1):
  for j in range(nc+1):
    if matriz[i][j] == 1:
      print(i,j)
```

Comment: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/traveling-salesman

Comment: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cvxpy

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `a != b` where `a bool, b bool` is equivalent to the constraint `a + b = 1`. (Keep in mind, that `!=` is an operator that won't work in general in cvxpy as it's not linear) Another remark: if you really solve a shortest-path problem, which is polynomially solvable, you should be able to model it without the need for any boolean/integer-based variables, but a pure LP.